# qml-TextArea disable background

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I want to disable or make the background of a `TextArea` transparent, but unfortunately it doesn't work (stays white all the time).

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    color: "grey"

    TextArea {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        backgroundVisible: false
    }
}
```

It doesn't change anything if I set `backgroundVisible` to `true` or `false`! What I am doing wrong? Does somebody has a solution for that (it could be a c++ fix, also)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just test your example (with qmlscene program provided by Qt5.1 SDK) and here is the output [http://postimg.org/image/uavoo28dj/](http://postimg.org/image/uavoo28dj/).

Comment: Strange. I am using qt 5.1 msvc2010 32 bit -> windows. What are you using?

Comment: I tried on Linux Mint 14 with gcc 4.7, but for instance I have no explanation for your problem. Only idea I have : have you defined a custom TextArea component in your qml source tree?

Comment: Could you show me your TextArea.qml?
Its located under: Qt\5.1.0\msvc2010\qml\QtQuick\Controls 
i guess gcc for you or whatever

Comment: Here it is : https://gist.github.com/vannell/cdb2833e0e48f5830d1c

Comment: Thanks. The part I was interested in, is the same... Seems to be a windows bug :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38483/discussion-between-jbh-and-immerhart)

Comment: It's work for me with window. Do you have your OpenGL driver updated ?

Comment: Should have mentioned this. This is a bug, which is solved in 5.2! But thanks.